# Can we connect to documentdb cluster through Route53 domain?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-route53, aws-route53

I registered a domain in Route53. I added a CNAME record and added value as documentdb cluster url with port (example: test.cluster.amazon.com:27017). I am trying to connect to documentdb using Route53 record name but I am unable to connect. Am I missing something or we can't ?

```java
protected MongoClient mongoClient(final String username, final String password, final String endpoint,
            final String readPreference) {
        final String template = "mongodb://%s:%s@%s/?ssl=true&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=%s&retryWrites=false";
        String connectionString = String.format(template, username, password, endpoint, readPreference);

        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(connectionString);
        LOGGER.info("DocumentDB connected to {}", endpoint);
        return mongoClient;
    }
```

Comment: May be the security group in the document db cluster is not correctly whitelisted to allow traffic from the external world.

Comment: @error404, I have connected to db cluster locally in Studio 3T.